# how to access controller.php files attributes?

Tags: php, yii

This is the Controller.php file of my yii project,
I have added one more attribute called $name1 in that.

```
<?php
/**
 * Controller is the customized base controller class.
* All controller classes for this application should extend from this base class.
 */
class Controller extends CController
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the controller view. Defaults to '//layouts/column1',
     * meaning using a single column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column1.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column1';
   /**
     * @var array context menu items. This property will be assigned to {@link CMenu::items}.
    */
    public $menu=array();
        public $name1 = array('test','test1','test3');

    /**
    * @var array the breadcrumbs of the current page. The value of this property will
    * be assigned to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}. Please refer to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}
       * for more details on how to specify this property.
    */
    public $breadcrumbs=array();
 }
```

So how can I access this attribute $name1, model, view and controller(if possible)...

Comment: You want to access this `$name1` variable in model, view and controller files?

Comment: In same controller (`$this->name1[0];` will return `test` as the value)

Comment: @kunal, the file I'm talking about is the main class from which we extend other controller classes.. so like breadcrumbs that you can see it is used in multiple views as $this->breadcrumbs =array(... etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it in your views as:

```
 $this->name1; //$this refers to the controller in the view, name1 is array as you declared.
```

You can access it in your model like:

```
 Yii::app()->controller->name1;
```

In your controllers it should be the same as in your views like:

```
$this->name1;
```

Comment: Can you type this `echo '<pre>'; print_r($this); echo '</pre>';` in your view and see if your $name1 array show there.

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake, now I got it working... and it is also show in view file like u said above..